# How to speed up my Rails 4 app on Heroku (tips for a n00b)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How to speed up my Rails app on Heroku? Will buying 2 dynos speed up my site significantly?

I found these tips and already implemented some of them on my Rails app, but I'm interested whether there are more?

- “Thin controller and fat model”
- Split views in separate partials
- Use of CDN
- Caching
- Using the asset Pipeline

Edit: Getting a downvote, so clearly something wrong with my question, too broad?

Comment: most essentially - LEARN

Comment: more dynos != performance. more dynos == more throughput

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will continue to learn more. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It probably would have been better if you asked about a specific part of performance you want to improve upon).

Here's a tip, use New Relic to ping your site and check that is still up and running:

1. you will be alerted to any issues
2. your Heroku app won't go to sleep which will increase its response time as it won't have to 'wake up' if no one has viewed your site for a while.

Plus use New Relic anyway as it has a wide range of features that are really useful for monitoring database requests, response times, etc.